# ArrayList saved in Shared Preferences behaving strangely

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, oncreate, onpause

In my app I have been using shared preferences for saving various types of data. I have been able to get the desired result using shared preferences before but I haven't been able to solve an issue with it.
I am saving an ArrayList in shared preferences in onPause method, getting saved data in OnCreate method and clearing the preferences in onBackPressed method. I have been able to finish this activity and still be able to get the ArrayList's data in Oncreate, but when I press the phone's back button twice and when the activity is created again I loose the data in ArrayList.

Here are parts of my code:

```
public class RecipientAddressActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ArrayList<Person> prev_recArray;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipient_address);
        prev_recArray = new ArrayList<Person>();
        loadPreferences();
        addListeners();
    }

    private void loadPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        if (prev_recArray.size() == 0) {
            int prev_recArraysize = sharedPreferences.getInt(
                "Prev_Rec_Size", 0);
            if (prev_recArraysize > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < prev_recArraysize; i++) {
                    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(
                        "PrevRecList_" + i, "");
                    Person p = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
                    prev_recArray.add(p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a button's click event, I add an item in the prev_recArray:

```
{
    Intent Recipient_info = new Intent();
    Person recipient = new Person(edt_rec_name.getText().toString(),
        edt_rec_addr1.getText().toString(), edt_rec_addr2.getText()
            .toString(), edt_rec_city.getText().toString(), edt_rec_state
            .getText().toString(), edt_rec_pcode.getText().toString(),
        edt_rec_country.getText().toString());
    prev_recArray.add(recipient);
    // ...
    finish();
}

private void showRecPicker() {
    final RecipientPicker rec_picker = RecipientPicker
        .newInstance("Select a    Recipient");
    Log.e("Before passing it to getAllRecipients Size", "RecPicker = "
        + prev_recArray.size());
    rec_picker.getAllRecipients(prev_recArray);
    if ((prev_recArray.size() == 0)) {
        AlertDialog no_recipients = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            RecipientAddressActivity.this).create();
        no_recipients.setMessage("No previous recipients.");
        no_recipients.setButton(RESULT_OK, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {}
            });
        no_recipients.show();
    } else {
        rec_picker.setListener(new RecipientPickerListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSelectRecipient(Person p) {
                loadPersonValues(p);
                rec_picker.dismiss();
            }
        });
        rec_picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "RECIPIENT_PICKER");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.e("In RecipientAddress", "On Pause");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    for (int i = 0; i < prev_recArray.size(); i++) {
        String json = gson.toJson(prev_recArray.get(i));
        editor.putString("PrevRecList_" + i, json);
    }
    editor.putInt("Prev_Rec_Size", prev_recArray.size());
    editor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.e("Phone's back button is presed", "Clearing SP");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Can someone please point out if I'm doing something wrong or missing something.

Comment: ` I press the phone's back button twice and when the activity is created again I loose the data in ArrayLis` because you are clearing data from SharedPreferences on back pressed. so please explain problem more

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I clear the SharedPreferences because the items get doubled up and moreover when I press phone's back button once the SharedPreferences still get cleared and populates again when it is created but when pressed twice..data is lost.

Comment: Leaving `//TODO autogenerated method stub` is a -1 - correct your formatting please. What is your problem again ? When you press twice do you see `Log.e("Phone's back button is presed", "Clearing SP");` twice ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D My problem is the Arraylist's (prev_recArray) items get cleared if I press the back button twice but retains when pressed once. I have used SharedPreferences to save data.

Comment: When you press it once do you see the `Log.e("Phone's back button is presed", "Clearing SP");` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Yes I can see Log.e("Phone's back button is presed", "Clearing SP"); once when back is pressed. So this current activity( Let say Activity D) is finished. Now in the previous activity(Activity C) if I press back button again it goes to Activity B and if I come back to Activity D the contents of the arraylist is lost. So when I come from Activity D to B  and back to D, I loose the arraylist's contents but the contents are retained if I go from Activity D to C and back to D.

Comment: @user2688158: somehow the prefs are rewritten in C or reentering in D from C - print the prefs in C